# Sharing a single boost C++ locale object between multiple processes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-locale

Currently working on a project to add [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) language translation.

The issue is that each time a process is launched, it loads a 13 MB translation file called *MOfiles\de_DE\LC_MESSAGES\msg.mo* ([.mo extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/MO-Files.html#MO-Files)) and takes approximately **1 second** to complete. Every new process suffers this same delay and it degrades the users overall experience.

**Question:** Is it possible to create a single translation object in shared memory, so that any new processes could reference that existing object and avoid the delay?

After some brief research, I found a Boost C++ [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) which creates a vector in shared memory.
Could it be adapted for a boost locale object too?

The single process translation file is currently loaded as follows

```
void STDCALL SetGlobalLocale(const char* domain, const char* locale, const char* path, const char* charset)
{
    std::string encoding(charset);
    encoding.insert(0,".");
    std::string language = locale ? (locale + encoding) : "";

    boost::locale::generator gen;

    gen.add_messages_path(path);
    gen.add_messages_domain(domain);

    // Sets a single global locale for the entire process.
    std::locale loc = gen(language);  // SLOW!!! Takes 1 second to load. ಠ_ಠ
    std::locale::global(loc);

    gen.clear_paths();
    gen.clear_domains();
}
```

and called using

```
SetGlobalLocale("msg", "de_DE", "../../../../MOfiles", "CP1252");
```

Comment: I find proposed solution hacky. Instead, I would address the "process startup latency" problem by arranging to launch the processes ahead of the time that they are needed.

Comment: I think we're going to spawn a separate "translator" thread during process creation to load the dictionary. This would allow language loading and general process startup code to run in parallel. Thanks for the idea!